# delete facebook requests via graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am getting latest apprequest like this:

```
FB.api('/me/apprequests', function(response){

if (response.data[0]) {     
// code here
};
```

How to delete apprequest using the same graph api method ,  I know this is possible with request containing access_token ... but in this case I am caching html and didn't know how

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the following code (PHP):

```
file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$rid.'?access_token='.$token.'&method=DELETE') == "true";   

// $rid: Request Id
// $token: Access Token

// The response is generally just the text "true"
```