# How to delete a video on Facebook using Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to delete a video on FaceBook using the Graph API.

After much research, the syntax would be as follows, according to some users:

```
$link = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$idFaceBook."_".$idVideo."?method=delete&access_token=".$token;
$output = curl($link);
```

Unfortunately, it returns the following JSON response:

```
{ "error": { "message": "(#100) This post could not be loaded", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 100 } }
```

Test 1:

```
$link = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$idFB."_".$video."?method=delete&access_token=".$_SESSION['tokenFB'];
$output = curl($link);  
echo $output;
```

Result:

```
{ "error": { "message": "(#100) This post could not be loaded", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 100 } }
```

Test 2:

```
$link = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$video."?method=delete&access_token=".$_SESSION['tokenFB'];
$output = curl($link);  
echo $output;
```

Result:

```
{ "error": { "message": "(#100) This post could not be loaded", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 100 } }
```

Test 3:

```
$link = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$video."_".$idFB."?method=delete&access_token=".$_SESSION['tokenFB'];
$output = curl($link);  
echo $output;
```

Result:

```
{ "error": { "message": "(#1705) Selected wall post for deletion does not exist.", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 1705 } }
```

I found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626943/delete-facebook-requests-via-graph-api).

But I received:

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need the `publish_actions` permission to delete a video, and of course a valid User Session of the user who posted it.

Here are some links with code to get you started:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/video
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-php-sdk-4-0-tutorial/

Check out the Facebook docs especially, it includes code in several languages for deleting a video.

**Important note from the docs:**

> A video can only be removed by the same app that published it.

Also, i am pretty sure you are trying with the wrong ID. I don´t think there is an underscore in the Graph Object ID. Try with the video ID only. And try to do a GET request to make sure the ID is correct.

Comment: Thank you for sharing me facebook documentation but I've read it before I start work on facebook API and before I ask my question =)

I already got the `publish_actions` permission, and a valid user session token, of course this is the same app who published it who delete it !

By the way, if i havn't got the permission, facebook call me something like "bad permissions".
Here, he said "Post could not be loaded", but Ids are true.

Other suggestions ?

Comment: well, you would be surprised how many people don´t read the docs ;) you also did not use code from the docs, so i figured you did not read it - i´ve added some more information, maybe it helps.